# Getting event default handler's result from jQuery handler

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

Let's say there is a DIV element with an `onclick` event:

```
<div onclick="return 'Hello world'"></div>
```

Now I want to get this 'Hello world' string from delegated jQuery event:

```
$('body').delegate('div', 'click', function(event){
    var s = ...; // Now s is 'Hello world'
});
```

Is it possible?

I need this as a workaround for a sophisticated IE bug, so IE-only solutions will do.

P.S. For those who wonder: the bug is that when in IE8 document mode, IE10 follows links within FORM elements even when there is `return false` in anchor's `onclick` handler.

Comment: What are you expecting that `return 'Hello World'` to actually do? The `return ` statement in an event handler of that sort just indicates whether or not to propagate the event. In this case the string will be `truthy` so the event will propagate. Colour me confused! What are you actually trying to achieve - there is probably a better way

Comment: Actually, `return false` doesn't stop event from propagation. It just prevents the event consequences.

Answer (score 1):

`var s = this.onclick();` Will do the trick, although it is not clear what your are trying to achieve...

Comment: It will fire the onclick handler one more time. This is not desired.

Comment: @Danylo: Then you have to parse the content of the attribute, which seems to be very hacky though.

Comment: My answer works well, assuming no side effects are involved as in your example

Comment: You're right. Unfortunately, in my case there will be side effects.

Answer (score 0):

A slight modification on your code:

```
<div onclick="alert('Hello world');">Hello World</div>
```

and

```
$('body').delegate('div', 'click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    exec($(this).attr('onclick'));
});
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/y7ABJ/

Another option as it's not clear what your goal is:

```
<div data-my-text="Hello world">Hello World</div>
```

and

```
$('body').delegate('div', 'click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var s = $(this).data('myText');
    alert(s);
});
```

Comment: For some reason event delegation doesn't work at JSFiddle: [http://jsfiddle.net/ARXV7/](http://jsfiddle.net/ARXV7/). And the first solution doesn't work actually (since the "onclick" handler is executed first and not the other way around). Unfortunately, the second solution isn't an option for me either.

Comment: Make sure you add a reference to jQuery (I chose 1.9.1) on the left side. And you can also use $('body').on('click', 'div', function(e) {});

Comment: You're right, the delegation works. But the code doesn't since, as I said, the "onclick" handler is executed first: [http://jsfiddle.net/UTHCM/](http://jsfiddle.net/UTHCM/).